# How can I filter relationship condition for multiple iteration specified with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to get all nodes and relationships matching certain condition in relationship.

```
MATCH(a:DB {TABLE:'CONT',COLUMN:'STATUS_CDE'})-[b:RELATED*..]->(c:DB)
WHERE b.CLAUSE IN ['where','join','unknown']  
RETURN a,b,c
```

But I got the below error message, when I tried to execute the above query.

```
Type mismatch: expected Map, Node or Relationship but was Collection<Relationship>
```

I am using Neo4j community edition v3.0.1.
How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use a variable depth for relationship type `RELATED` - `b` is now a collection of relationships, not a single relation upon which you can use the IN operator.

Depending on whether you want every relationship to have one of these values, or just some/one, you can use one of the [predicate](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-predicates) functions like this

```
MATCH(a:DB {TABLE:'CONT',COLUMN:'STATUS_CDE'})-[b:RELATED*..]->(c:DB)
WHERE all(rel in b where rel.name in ['where','join','unknown'])
RETURN a,b,c
```

(untested)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got the result that I wanted to get.